# What dlls from Gallio do I need to include for TeamCity to run the tests

Tags: teamcity, mbunit, gallio

I'm using Gallio and MbUnit 3, and I have Team City 4 installed.  I just put the whole bin directory of Gallio into Subversion since I didn't know what dlls I needed.  Do you know which ones I need to keep, and what I don't need to put into SCM?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much of the bin directory is required but you can strip out plugins and folders for things you don't need, such as Visual Studio support, ReSharper extensions, AutoCAD integration, etc.

The easiest way to get this right is to perform a base-bones custom install of just the few Gallio components you really need such as MSBuild and TeamCity bits.  Then you can copy those bits into your source tree.

OTOH, bits are cheap so it might not be worth worrying about it too much...

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  I think I just needed some confirmation that I wasn't crazy for adding it all to SVN.  I've even put the docs and all in on occasion.  Don't know that I'll continue to do that in the future, but as you say bits are cheap!

Comment: @Lance - We typically add the distribution as it's packaged to our source tree: docs, binaries, and all.  It makes it easier to drop a new package in its place for future releases.